# Distinguish between point and any other spatial type

Tags: point, select-by-attribute, multipoint

When running an ST_INTERSECTION query on two linestrings in PostGIS, I expect it to return a point (e.g. 'POINT(1 2)'). This works 99,99 % of the time.  However, sometimes (for whatever reason), my query returns e.g. a MultiPoint, LineString, ... or any other spatial type.  In that case, I simply want to skip my queryResult and move to the next row in my table.

So I am looking for something like :

```
  if queryResult.SpatialType() = POINT:
         'do something'
  elif queryResult.SpatialType() != POINT:
         pass
```

But I cannot get anything like this to work.

What would be the correct statement to make a proper distinction between a point as the queryResult and any other spatial type ?

Comment: What software? If linestrings intersects at several points the result is multipoint, if lines are overlapping the common section is linestring, is they are many then multilinestring, and if there are also point/multipoint intersections the result is a geometry collection. I am surprised if you get any other combinations.

Comment: yes, I have tried ST_GeometryType but with no luck so far

Comment: Qgis, Postgis and Python

Comment: You should show how you have tried to use ST_GeometryType. This gives ST_Point `select ST_GeometryType(ST_GeomFromText('POINT (0 0)'))`.

Comment: SELECT ST_GeometryType(ST_aseWKT(
                        ST_Intersection(
                            ST_SetSRID(
                                (SELECT "GeomCommuneLINE" FROM public."LINE"
                                WHERE "osm_id" = '123456789'),4326),
                            ST_SetSRID(
                                (SELECT "GeomCommuneLINE" FROM public."LINE"
                                WHERE "osm_id" = '987654321'),4326)
                        )))

Comment: SetSRID should be unnecessary, I suppose that the geometries are in a known coordinate system in the table. BTW is it 4326 or 3857 in your database?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I try to use ST_SetSRID as much as possible since I am using all different geometries from different (download)sources and moving them around from PostGis to Qgis and vice versa.  As for my original problem, I can ofcourse buld a workaround by using an 'if..; else' statement (based on ST_GeometryType(), but I was hoping for a more direct approach without the 'if ..else'

Comment: Don't you ever experience that you have set a wrong SRID with an unnecessary manual ST_SetSRID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an ugly example but it works. Intersection in the first query is a point and 1 row is returned, while in the second query intersection is a LineString and no rows are returned.

```
select * from
(select ST_Intersection((ST_GeomFromText('linestring (0 0,1 1)')),
(ST_GeomFromText('linestring (0 1,1 0)'))) geom)
as a
where 
ST_GeometryType(a.geom)='ST_Point';


select * from
(select ST_Intersection((ST_GeomFromText('linestring (0 0,1 1)')),
(ST_GeomFromText('linestring (0 0,1 1)'))) geom)
as a
where ST_GeometryType(a.geom)='ST_Point';
```